# Background not where it is supposed to be [CSS/HTML]

Tags: html, css

i just started learning CSS/HTML and i am copying BBC's website. I have 3 different backgrounds [white/2 reds], and they are not the lengths they should be

Here is the code:
http://jsbin.com/viyuxomiyu/edit?html,output

### newsbar, #topicmenu, #topmenudiv

I have tried everything that was recommended in similar questions, but i still cant get the backgrounds to span the entire page.

Comment: by length do you mean vertically? or horizontally? They look fine to me.

Comment: horizontally. the bottom bar specifically doesnt extend across a normal page

Comment: Looks fine in chrome and IE. Both the red and dark red span the width of the page. (The content does not);

Comment: http://jsbin.com/haxoso/edit?html,output   i updated it to make it more obvious. if you scroll to the right u see that the two red bars are not the same length

Comment: The bar at the top is the width of the page, where the bar with the links in is the width of its content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to expand the background to 100% width if the div has a fixed width. What you should do is wrap the div:

```
<div style="width: 100%, background-color: red"> // full width
    <div class="fixedwidth" style="margin: auto"> //Content div. Margin auto will make the div centered horizontally
```

Comment: I just don't understand why the two bars are different lengths when they should both be 1009px exactly.

Comment: They are. The div under #newsbar containing the image and rss feed is 1009 px. You need to apply the fixedwidth to #newsbar as divs are block elements and naturally take the full width of their parent.

Comment: Thank you. i mistakenly had the fixedwith above the <div id> for #topicmenu instead of below it, but that comment solved it.